# Informatica Repository files location

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am facing a kind of strange behavior as I am dealing with a mapping, so then the session with it assosciated and so the workflow(I created the workflow from the mapping). I even runned the workflow multiple times and even read and wrote to 2 Target tables.

Though the result are not yet logically correct, the fact that the source where read and the target wrote(a target table on oracle was complitely empty before the run), the mappign was for sure NOT invalid. 
Unfortunately PowerCenter crashed and once I opened it it gave me that the mapping I was using was invalid.

After few check I found out the Repositiry Manager is still associating an old source table to that mapping(but before was not) and giving me the following:

*Start validating 1 object(s). Fetching m_scbesc_storage21 (version 1) Validating m_scbesc_storage21 (version 1) Validating transformations of mapping m_scbesc_storage21... ...transformation validation completed with no errors. Validating data flow of mapping m_scbesc_storage21... ...(WARNING)link precision mismatch: from  FDS_EINKAUFUMSATZ: PK_ID  to  SQ_FDS_EINKAUFUMSATZ: PK_ID. This may lead to unexpected behaviour. ...(WARNING)link precision mismatch: from  FDS_EINKAUFUMSATZ: MONAT  to  SQ_FDS_EINKAUFUMSATZ: MONAT. This may lead to unexpected behaviour. ...input sources to SQ SQ_FDS_EINKAUFUMSATZ1 have no relationship. ...there are data flow validation errors. Parsing mapping m_scbesc_storage21... ...parsing completed with no errors.
******** Mapping m_scbesc_storage21 is INVALID ********
************ Finish validation.*

But actually the object it is refering is not been used anymore by the mapping(yes I did deleted it from the mapping, then refershed the workflow and validated it, and this stage was when I was able to run the workflow).

Indeed I cannot see the specific object associated with the specific mapping, but I can see it in the repository Manager.
Unfortunately I cannot delete if from the Repository Manager(as I am able to do instaed for other) and our licence has not yet the versioning support.

Would be a solution try to delete the object phisically, as it is not associated with other workflow?

If so where I can found in the Informatica folder the Repository Manager files?

If not how I could proceed keeping into account that I cannot use Versioning feature?

Here how you can see that source is not anymore in the mapping from repository Manager Tree View:

[mapping structure from Repository tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVA4M.png)

or from the Power Designer:

[mapping structure from Designer tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNeaN.png)

But as from the log error repository Manager has started to refer to it again, and I am not able to delete it anymore:

Comment: Is your repository versioned or not?

Comment: As far as I know it is not. As wrote we have a basic licence that does not comes with versioning

Comment: I just realized that the error say that SQ SQ_FDS_EINKAUFUMSATZ1 has no relationship, but has can be seen from the image(that I cannot upload), that is completely wrong,because that obj is connected. Indeed it is where where I do have the Override SQL

Comment: I think this question is partly based on the misconception that the infa/powercenter repository is xml based. Your mapping/session/workflow metadata is stored in a relational database which you can possibly query with SQL

Comment: @Lars I am aware that there is a database. Actually I know that Informatica powercenter use H2 database Engine, but this tsill does not aswer the question, as I don't want simply query it, I want to be able to refer the folder where object are stored, so really I don't care if they are xml(as they are), json or other format

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting and importing. You can try to review the XML file & fix it if needed. Keep in mind exporting from Mapping Designer is different then using Repository Manager. You can try both. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Maciejq it worked exporting the object(my mapping) from designer and then making some change to it and again importing it(from Repository--> export object). It did not solved my problem though. Actually I found the root of it, is due of a common error :https://kb.informatica.com/solution/9/Pages/9804.aspx. I would still know where xml files saved from PowerCenter

Comment: Ok, so now you'd just need to "Add a User Defined Join in the Source Qualifier." as the KB solution indicates.